# Mailgun API is not working with more complex JSON array/deep variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

I am attempting to deal with a receipt. I send in a big batch of json data for the multiple items I may be dealing with. Here is the ruby code.

```
      @bookings = Booking.last
      @bookings = @bookings.to_json(include: [:user_detail, 
 :products])
      booking = Booking.last
    
      RestClient.post "https://api:"\
      "@api.mailgun.net/v3/.mailgun.org/messages",
      :from => "MakeaCamp <mailgun@.mailgun.org>",
      :to => booking.user_detail.email,
      :template => "billingtest",
      :subject => "Receipt",
      :text => "Receipt",
      :'recipient-variables' => '{"' + booking.user_detail.email + '":  ' + @bookings + ' }'
```

Here is an example of what the json looks like. I am able to get the highest most level just fine such as **id** and **total_price**

`{"id":45,"total_price":45.00, "products":[{"id":1,"name":"Basic 1","description":"Basic product","price":"30.0"}], "user_detail":{"id":68,"first_name":"Bob"}}`

From my research I thought this was possible but it is not working. It is just printing the for loop stuff within the email as text. I also have tried something that is deep in the json seems to not work as well such as if I were to do **%receipt.user_detail.first_name%**.

```
{% for product in recipient.products %}
   <tr>
       <td>%product.name%</td>
       <td >$%product.price%</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If this is not a feature. Anything to work around this would be helpful.

Comment: A) It's 2021 and Ruby 1.8 is long dead, so you can use `from: '...'` instead of the clunky old `:from => '...'` notation. B) Are you sure you're supposed to compose JSON inline like that? Even if you are, use `JSON.dump` and not string concatenation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the [MailGun example](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending) to the modern Ruby style:

```rb
RestClient.post(
  "https://api:#{API_KEY}@api.mailgun.net/v3/.mailgun.org/messages",
  from: "MakeaCamp <mailgun@.mailgun.org>",
  to: booking.user_detail.email,
  template: "billingtest",
  subject: "Receipt",
  text: "Receipt",
  'recipient-variables' => JSON.dump(booking.user_detail.email => @bookings)
)
```

The key here is use of `JSON.dump` to properly encode whatever you might have there.

Comment: I added more so you can see what my variables booking and bookings were equal to. My json was already encoded correctly. As I said it was picking up the values. Just none that were arrays or deep. So it might be a thing with mailgun not providing these features... or there is a different way to do this.

Thanks for the help though on the more modern ruby, but it did not work on the email end, it sent successfully though, but variables are not working.

Comment: The syntax is just a minor thing. What's important here is `JSON.dump` which will correctly encode the variables. If you don't use that you're going to get a mess, *especially* if `@bookings` is a non-trivial structure.